# How can I calculate the idle time of the workplace if I have the start time/end time of intervals of overlapping work?

Tags: python, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I have a PostgreSQL database containing three columns: One for personal number of the worker, one for start time/end time, one for type of respective action (either Start or Break).

How can I find out which time is not utilized during the day?

```
 personal_number | callback_time | callback_type
-----------------+---------------+---------------
 18000130        | 11:05:31      | Start
 18000130        | 12:58:07      | Break
 18000130        | 12:58:14      | Start
 18000130        | 13:33:46      | Break
 18000130        | 13:33:52      | Start
 18000130        | 14:00:16      | Break
 18000168        | 13:59:35      | Start
 18000168        | 14:29:41      | Break
 18000168        | 14:29:53      | Start
 18000168        | 15:31:52      | Break
 18000168        | 15:32:04      | Start
 18000168        | 17:26:05      | Break
 18000168        | 17:26:14      | Start
 18000168        | 18:52:15      | Break
 18000168        | 21:05:39      | Start
 18000168        | 21:47:12      | Break
 18000241        | 05:58:15      | Start
 18000241        | 05:58:57      | Break
 18000241        | 06:00:13      | Start
 18000241        | 09:15:10      | Break
 18000241        | 09:37:17      | Start
 18000241        | 10:35:15      | Break
 18000241        | 10:35:25      | Start
 18000241        | 11:05:39      | Break
 18000241        | 11:05:47      | Start
 18000241        | 12:58:22      | Break
 18000241        | 12:58:30      | Start
 18000241        | 13:35:08      | Break
 18000241        | 13:35:15      | Start
 18000241        | 14:00:23      | Break
 18002441        | 02:55:20      | Start
 18002441        | 03:12:44      | Break
 18002441        | 03:12:56      | Start
 18002441        | 04:07:41      | Break
 18002441        | 22:30:47      | Start
```

I can calculate the time which is utilized for each worker (as a sum of differences between the start and the break). However these workers can work in parallel so simple formula 24 hours - work time will not work. Unless I can calculate the overlapping work hours, which is something I am unable to accomplish too.

I can also calculate the time that is not utilized BEFORE the first start and AFTER the last break.

I have no clue how to calculate the time that is not utilized during the rest of a day, i. e. how to sum the intervals of no-work.

I am trying to do this in Python, but I am open for any ideas.

Comment: What is the expected output?  Your description is somewhat helpful, but the actual expected output from your input data would be much more helpful.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, either a single value (amount of time during which no work was done), or the list of intervals of no-work time. In explicit: either 4 hours or 10:00-11:00 and 13:00-16:00.